# What is the purpose of blue crystals in Darksiders 2?

Tags: darksiders-2

About an hour ago I've started playing Darksiders II and I've wandered into 2 of these blue hovering crystals that make a sort of continuous church bell sound. I've tried to get near to them but I didn't manage to find a path to them.

Here's a screenshot of one of them:

[image]

Are these interactable and if so what do they do or are they just a part of the scenery?

Comment: Hiya, Aerus, and welcome to the site! I've gone ahead and pictorified your question! Cheers!

Comment: @RavenDreamer - No freehand circle? I'm disappointed.

Comment: @SaintWacko not my picture :P

Comment: @RavenDreamer - Oh, alright. I suppose that's acceptable then :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ben's answer is technically right, but not very detailed, and the post he links to is quite misleading. I'm going to put the rest of this in spoilers, so only mouse over if you want to know what they are.

> The crystals are a food of sorts for a construct named Blackroot. You do not have to wait til you get the Tremor Gauntlet to collect them, as they can be broken with Redemption, after you talk to Blackroot, who can be found in the Western bend of The Fjord.

Comment: I think, having clicked on the question, most people who read this will in fact want to know what these are.

Comment: @kotekzot - Yes, true. I'm not sure why I put that in spoilers :P Oh, well, I'll leave them there; it doesn't do any harm.

Answer (score 0):

According to this:

http://au.gamespot.com/darksiders/forum/blue-breakable-crystals-in-the-drowned-pass-53023394/

They are breakable and something happens when you break them.

Answer (score -1):

These are Stonebites they are part of a side quest according to this:

http://www.nowgamer.com/cheats/darksiders-2-cheats/1549263/darksiders_2_collectables_stonebites_relics_book_of_the_dead_locations.html

Answer (score -2):

You speak to a small kind of construct which isn't a construct and he will tell you he is hungry.  He gives you something which allows you to shoot them which will make you absorb them. It is also possible to get red ones, but I do not know what other colours are possible to collect .